# Stripe Bi-Weekly Subscription Description

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

Using Stripe's PHP API I was able to create a bi-weekly subscription for my customers but I'm having an issue, the "description" on all subscriptions is defaulting to "Subscription creation" and I can't seem to find a way to add a description although I thought the following code worked in the past (I updated the API since then). Please see my code below

```
        case "BiWeekly":
        try {
            $product = \Stripe\Product::create([
                "name" => "NEO Bi-Weekly Payments for $cname",
                "type" => "service",
                "statement_descriptor" => "NEO",
            ]);

            $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create([
                "product" => $product->id,
                "amount" => $totalAmount,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "interval" => "week",
                "interval_count" => 2,
                "usage_type" => "licensed",
            ]);

            $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
                "customer" => $customer->id,
                "items" => [["plan" => $plan->id]],
                "metadata" => array("Name" => $cname, "For" => "NEO Bi-Wkly Pymts")
            ]);
            
            } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
                $body = $e->getJsonBody();
                $err  = $body['error'];
                header("Location: https://www.neo.com/declined/");
                exit();
            };
    break;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Then try `description` https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create?lang=php#create_product-description

Comment: i don't  know  how/where to apply it on the code, i tried but it didn't work

Comment: You should be seeing `description='Subscription creation'` on the corresponding PaymentIntent (not the Subscription). The subscription will always automatically populate the description for the generated PaymentIntent afaik. You can update the PaymentIntent's description later, however, why do you need to do so?

Comment: @alex thanks for responding! On the "Payments" tab I just see "Subscription creation" as you said vs the description I'd like such as "Name x For NEO Bi-Wekly Pymts", however when I go to the "Products" tab I do see the subscription there labeled properly as "NEO Bi-Weekly Payments for x". I'd just LOVE to see the description in the "Payments" tab to show "Name x For NEO Bi-Wekly Pymts" that's the part I'm having a hard time populating via the code above.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments - `description='Subscription creation'` is on the corresponding PaymentIntent (not the Subscription).

There's no easy way to do this - it's not possible to specify a description when creating the Subscription to automatically populate on the corresponding PaymentIntent.

What I suggest is to :

1. Create the Subscription with [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-metadata)
2. listen for the [invoice.payment_succeeded](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded) webhook event - https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks
3. The `invoice.payment_succeeded` will contain the `metadata` from step 1 in [lines](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-lines) and the [payment_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-payment_intent)

Example

```
...
"lines": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "il_...",
          "object": "line_item",
          ...
          "metadata": {
            "subscription_metadata": "some_value"
          },
  ...
"payment_intent": "pi_...",
...
```

4. using the data from step 3, make a request to [update the PaymentIntent's description](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update)

On a side note, you should no longer be creating `Plans` (which is deprecated), but should be creating [Prices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices) instead.